# how to redirect the to a particular page when just domain name is typed in?

Tags: .htaccess, webserver, redirect, httpd.conf

I am looking on how to ask the apache webserver to redirect to a particular page of mine when just domain name is typed in with no path.
Example : 
if a user types **mydomain.com** it should redirect him to **mydomain.com/pages/home.html**.
but if the user types any path after the domain i.e. if the user types

mydomain.com/releaseNotes or 
mydomain.com/configurationGuide

it should redirect according to the request with out considering the rule i have set for mydomain.com

Here is my full .htaccess file.

**ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ pages/home.html [L]**

thanks,
Naga

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ /pages/home.html [L,R]
```

Comment: Hi Anubhava, Thanks for the response. I tried this but it does not work. It redirects me to 404 - NotFound. Is there anything else that i am missing here ?

Comment: Yes i can open , when i hit the url directly it works.

Comment: i Have tried various options in Redirect command. Can you let me know if it can be done with Redirect command ?

Comment: Hi Anubhava, The above never worked for me. Can you suggest any troubleshoot or other routes for achieving the same

Comment: What happens when you visit `mydomain.com/pages/home.html` in your browser.

Comment: it redirects me to 404 - Not Found

Comment: If `mydomain.com/pages/home.html` causes 404 then how come you wrote this requirement: **Example : if a user types mydomain.com it should redirect him to mydomain.com/pages/home.html**

Comment: Sry i put it wrong, when i hit mydomain.com/pages/home.html it redirects me to my home page. When i hit mydomain.com after giving the RewriteRule, it redirects me to 404.

Comment: How is `mydomain.com/pages/home.html` getting redirected to home page? Do you have some 404 handler set? Does `/pages/home.html` really exist?